# eyedropper tool working incorrectly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

By default when sampling colors in Photoshop with the eyedropper the color selected shows up as the foreground color, currently when i try sampling a color it sets it as the background color -how can i fix this error? (any clues how this change occurred?)

Comment: Is your Alt or Option key stuck?  If not, reset the preferences.

Comment: @Scott no everything is the way it should be-that was the first think i checked when this behavior started

Comment: @Scott I am reluctant to reset all preferences & thats why im asking this question

Comment: Well, there's no substitute for resetting prefs. If something isn't operating as expected that's the first line of troubleshooting. You can always **move** preferences files and restart the app to see if that corrects the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to left-click on **Foreground colour swatch** in your **Color** panel. The tricky part is to determine if Foreground or Background colour swatch is selected.

This is probably what you have now:

[image: Background colour swatch selected] [image: Background colour swatch selected (magnified)]

And this is how it should look like:

[image: Foreground colour swatch selected] [image: Foreground colour swatch selected (magnified)]